# Play video files problem, Graphics card issue?

Tags: 12.04, graphics

Recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS;
Problem: When I play video files, I only get sound, no video whatsoever, Youtube video work though.

How do I fix this ?
There's not video card installed, just using the internal graphics from mobo.

Motherboard: Asus p5vd2-mx

Answer (score 0):

DID U INSTALL:   https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/

A VIDEO PLUGIN.SEE IF THIS HELPS

Comment: Yes, it's installed by default

Comment: then try: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras and sudo apt-get install vlc. this shall solve it.

Comment: Still nothing, (I installed VLC before all this)

Comment: If u've installed restricted extras, then probably you need to install drivers from the vendor's site.Whats the o/p of : lspci | grep VGA

Comment: What u mean by o/p of : lspci | grep VGA?

Comment: output of the command:   lspci | grep VGA      in your terminal

Comment: How am I supposed to install the drivers from the vendor's site if all of them are made for Windows ?

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. P4M890 [S3 UniChrome Pro] (rev 01)

Comment: lets experiment with vlc:   Tools > Preferences > Show settings "All" > Video > Output modules > Video output module > OpenGL video output.Tell me what you get.

Comment: First time: It showed the beginning of the video file, although it didn't play at all, the screen froze, used control+alt+del to get out
Second time: Couldn't get out

Comment: I set the Video output module to Standard again and it worked. Thank you so much for your help :D

Comment: -1 : That's lame,First you've got "Still nothing, (I installed VLC before all this) ", and switching back to "DEFAULT" suddenly worked!

Comment: Yeah, kinda hard to believe, but I think it's due to VLC not getting applied changes directly ( restricted extras). Temporarily setting it to another video output module and back again actually made it apply. Not lying about the issue though, if you think I did.